# Долгое чтение файла

Tags: c#, excel

При открытии excel-файла с помощью Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel чтение идет слишком долго:

```cs
source_workbook = source_ex.Workbooks.Open(source_doc.Trim(),
                  Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                  Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                  Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                  Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

xlsx-файл в 13Мб открывается за 9 секунд, такой же, но xlsb-файл - 6 минут. Причем обращению к диску практически нет. При долгом открытии i7 с 8 потоками сжирается на ~80%. В чем может быть проблема?
[Ссылка на проект](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/Undn_Mi6XRa2bw) Там же и тестовые файлы

Comment: _Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel чтение идет слишком долго_ - это норма для офисного интеропа. А если серьезно, то работа с COM объектами офиса намного сложнее, чем кажется. Там куча ограничений, например нельзя создавать COM объект в одном потоке, а использовать в другом. Нельзя забывать очищать ресурсы, и еще много всякого нельзя, о чем в рамках одной показанной строчки кода говорить сложно. В общем, там целая наука. И даже если сильно постараться - без воспроизводимого примера найти причину невозможно.

Comment: @aepot, ссылку  прикрепил. Но после тестирования выяснилось, что все время тратится именно на метод ``Workbooks.Open()`` Что в нем происходит -  хороший вопрос. Кстати, только на моем компьютере xlsx-файлы открываются быстро...

Comment: 1) `target_ex.Quit();` забыли 2) `await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ...)` поменяйте на `await Task.Run(() => ...)` возможно у вас возникает исключение, но вы его не видите. Подробно расписывать не буду, просто почитайте, в чем разница между `Factory.StartNew` и `Run`. 3) обращаться к контролам на форме из рабочего потока нельзя, нужно использовать `Form.Invoke` 4) ну и по мелочи, вместо `readonly string` можно `const string`. В общем кроме незакрытого экселя я пока больше ничего не вижу страшного.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо) Стоило сказать, что проект клепался быстро, без учета всех перечисленных Вами моментов. Тут важно одно - в чем проблема с долгим чтением) Перечисленные недочеты, конечно, будут после этого исправлены

Comment: У вас после первого запуска незакрытый эксель остается висеть. Поправьте, и перепроверьте, а вдруг поможет. Проверьте диспетчер задач на предмет зависших экселей, поубивайте их.

Comment: Как насчет создать эти 2 экселя в разных потоках? Прикрутить  `ManualResetEventSlim`, чтобы принимающий эксель дождался данных, и только потом писал. Во всяком случае они хоть запукаться и книжки свои открывать будут одновременно.

Comment: 1) ``target_ex.Quit()`` добавил) Без изменений. Хотя и до этого оставшиеся excel-окна закрывал (оставались после  закрытия программы с ошибками) Хоть тресни, а Исходный.xlsb читает 8 минут (в этот раз 8). С Итог.xlsb проблем нет вообще - практически моментально читает. 
2) Т.к. второй файл открывается намного быстрее, то, думаю, нет смысла делать 2 потока. Все утыкается в ``Workbooks.Open()``. Что ему не нравится - хороший  вопрос

Comment: _нет смысла делать 2 потока_ - а вы попытайтесь, это же просто, делов минут 15. Я вот например не уверен, как 2 экселя у вас уживаются в одном потоке, может им тесно.

Comment: Нет ли там сложных формул, ссылок на другие файлы? Помню когда-то давно сильно помогало отключать калькуляцию и обновление экрана при загрузке экселя через интероп.

Comment: @aepot, почему же тогда с xlsx-файлом все прекрасно?))

Comment: Я в гадалки играю, что вижу - то пою. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50551508/12888024 можно действитель еще `Calculation` отрубить. `Task.Run` исправили? Еще какие-то [параметры открытия](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open?view=excel-pia) возможно можно добавить.

Comment: При установки ``Calculation`` вылетает ошибка: ``System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: "Исключение из HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"`` Какое бы значение не устанавливал. ``Task.Run`` исправлено

Comment: Ну вот, теперь хоть ошибки видно. :) По ошибке не знаю, чем помочь.